# #Python CodeBreaker in Python

Tags: python, exit

I'm a fairly new programmer and I'm trying to do a type of BlackJack were when you get 21 or over 21 the code "break". Or the code do not keep on running.

I have tried exit() and sys.exit() but at the end this keeps popping up "An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit" and I wonder if there is another type of command to break the code from running but without an error message.

Player = input()

if Player == "Hit me":

```
print("You have",x+y,)
if x+y == 21:
  print("You win")
  sys.exit() 
elif x+y > 21:
  print("You loose")
  sys.exit()
```

this is a part of it or more so the part that I want to change with the "sys.exit()". 
BTW the x and y you see is variables that are assigned random numbers in the beginning.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: The best way to stop the program from running is to reach the end of the code. This can simply be archived by having a `main()` function and returning from it.

Comment: Pleaase post your code to get more understanding of what you are doing wrong,

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on a forced exit from the program - instead, build-in the exit case to your code. Without seeing your code it's difficult to be specific, but an example structure would be:

```
score = 0
while score < 21:
    score = black_jack(score)

print("You scored {}!".format(score))
```

Where the `black_jack()` function contains your code to simulate a round of the card game.

Comment: Thanks alot for you comment. I'm right now trying to make up a new code that fits with this because my last one was a total mess.

Comment: I have taken use of your example code and today marks the day that i finished this faily simple project. And instead of my previous code with about 200 lines I manege to get it down to about 33 lines of code with the use of your while loop.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, huge improvement in code efficiency! Onwards and upwards...